# What is the point of left-shifting by zero?

Tags: java

I am looking through the verboden sun.misc.Unsafe code, and I see quite a few instances of, eg,

```
//Gives an absolute address given the base address & an offset i
private long ix(int i) {
    return address + (i << 0);
}
```

At first glance this doesn't, and shouldn't, do anything a plain `address + i` wouldn't, yet the idiom appears all over.  What's going on here?

Comment: Which Java version? I don't see it in openjdk 6 or 7.

Comment: It looks similar, but I wouldn't dupe-vote it just yet. I don't think `sun.misc.Unsafe` is actually autogenerated code; it doesn't appear to be autogenerated in any version I've seen.

Comment: Look through some of the other answers. Although, the OP of the other question never chose a "best answer", the answers revolve around "theres no use to it"

Comment: @user2357112 I'm looking specifically at the Oracle JDK.